# Is it possible to insert links between two background images [one is a set of opening doors]

Tags: wordpress, image, hyperlink, background, layer

So basically the situation is i have a set of salon doors that open on click, and behind them are two posters [one for each door] that need to be linked to other pages. I cant figure this out, and im starting to think it isnt actually possible.

Here is the link to the page [link to page](http://www.visualiseitinprogress.co.uk/gringos/wordpress/)

any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Also apologies for any messy code, im still in need of more coffee!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things like this are always possible. However it can be confusing to get the right structure in place.

You'll have to rearrange some of the structure of your HTML. It's HTML5, so we are able to wrap the anchor tag around the DIV element.

1) Keep following HTML structure: `a > div.clickhere > h2`.

2) Update CSS `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left` properties for `.clickhere`.

3) Declare a `position: absolute;` to `h2` with `bottom` and `left` properties to reposition the text.

Screenshot attached below.

[image]